# CTE to get all children and nested children of every parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-server-2019

I'm stuck in a problem that continuously hammering in my mind to find the solution.

I have a `users` table with 6k of rows and they are related as `parent-child`. The problem is that I want results not only at a single level parent-child relationship but at all levels (until the last child) for every `userid`.

I have this data in my `users` table.

```
UserID | ParentID
1        NULL
2        1
3        1
4        2
5        2
6        5
7        6
8        6
9        NULL
```

I want this data as the output of CTE.

```
ParentID  |  UserID
1            1
1            2
1            3
1            4
1            5
1            6
1            7
1            8
2            2
2            4
2            5
2            6
2            7
2            8
3            3
4            4
5            5
5            6
5            7
5            8
6            6
6            7
6            8
7            7
8            8
9            9
```

Note: The ParentID includes not only its children but also children of its children and itself too. I'm using MSSQL 2019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first part of cte select all the rows with ownid as root id. Then in second part (after union all) select parentid as rootid.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table users (UserID int,  ParentID int);
 insert into users values (1,        NULL);
 insert into users values (2,        1);
 insert into users values (3,        1);
 insert into users values (4,        2);
 insert into users values (5,        2);
 insert into users values (6,        5);
 insert into users values (7,        6);
 insert into users values (8,        6);
 insert into users values (9,        NULL);
```

Query:

```
 with cte as
 (
   select userid rootid, userid, parentid from users 
   union all
   select cte.rootid rootid, users.userid, users.parentid from users
   inner join cte on users.parentid=cte.userid
 )
 select rootid parentid,userid from cte
 order by rootid ,userid
 option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Output:

| parentid | userid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 5 | 7 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 |
| 9 | 9 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45389ce7f94ad047838578f76a21dd53)*